# ng new fails with "SyntaxError: Unexpected token =" on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, and I installed npm and node by using `sudo apt-get install npm node`. After that I installed `@angular/cli` with `sudo npm install @angular/cli -g`.

But when I try to create a new project with `ng new hello-world`, it fails with this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:17
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
```

How do I make `ng new` work?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was because Ubuntu has an old version of node in the repos. I fixed the error by installing a more recent version following the instructions at https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```