# Does npm track package compatibility?

Tags: npm

If I have an old version of node (for example downloaded from Ubuntu repos), and I use `sudo npm install @angular/cli -g`, will that download the last version of `@angular/cli` that is known to work with that version of node, or will that always install the latest version of `@angular/cli`, even if that version is incompatible with my version of node?

I'm asking because I [encountered a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973352/ng-new-fails-with-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-on-ubuntu) that makes me think that the second variant is what takes place. But at the same time, my experience with package managers like `apt-get` has led me to believe that they generally make sure to install compatible versions - `apt-get` will not install packages for `Ubuntu 17.10.1` if your distro is `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`, for example.

So I'm curious to know if `npm` behaves more like `apt-get` in that regard, or not.

Comment: Just a side note, but you shouldn't be running `sudo npm install` anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm does not behave like apt get in that regard, if you run `npm install -g <package>`, npm will download the latest version of that package from the registry, regardless of which Node version you have installed.

We can actually test this using the @angular/cli example. As can be read on the [project's homepage](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli):

> Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node 6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.

So if I downgrade my Node version to the final 5.x release:

```
$ nvm install 5.12.0
Downloading and installing node v5.12.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.12.0/node-v5.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100,0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v5.12.0 (npm v3.8.6)
```

And then run `npm install @angular/cli -g`, you can see that npm couldn't care less which version of Node I am running:

```
$ npm ls -g --depth=0
/home/jack/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/lib
├── @angular/cli@1.7.1
└── npm@3.8.6
```

As a side note, you might want to look into using a Node version manager, as this will mean you don't need to run `npm install` using sudo. Here's a [good guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/) if you're interested. This is especially relevant in regard to the recent npm shenanigans (ref.: [Unlucky Linux boxes trampled by NPM code update, patch zapped](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/02/23/npm_undoes_patch/))